# Entity Framework Core 3.0, No Migrations Were Applied. The database is already up to date. NOT Working

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.0, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to update the database using migrations, but in the attempt I receive the following message 'No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date'. I know that indicates that there has been no changes in the code to apply a certain update to the database, but it shows the message even when the code has been edited to make a change in the database.

Note: The command 'Add-Migrations' works perfectly.

I leave some related code.

Beforehand, Thank You!!

```
namespace MasterGym.Persistence.Models
{
    public class MasterGymContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MasterGymContext>
    {
        public MasterGymContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("AppSettings.json").Build();
            var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("MasterGymModel");
            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MasterGymContext>();
            builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

            return new MasterGymContext(builder.Options);
        }
    }
}

namespace MasterGym.Persistence.Models
{
    public class MasterGymContext : DbContext
    {
        public MasterGymContext(DbContextOptions<MasterGymContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EmergencyContact> EmergencyContacts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EmergencyDoctor> EmergencyDoctors { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MedicalQuestionnaire> MedicalQuestionnaires { get; set; }
        public DbSet<GeneralQuestionnaire> GeneralQuestionnaires { get; set; }
        public DbSet<DiseaseQuestionnaire> DiseaseQuestionnaires { get; set; }
        public DbSet<InjuryQuestionnaire> InjuryQuestionnaires { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(MasterGymContext).Assembly);
        }
    }
}

namespace MasterGym.Persistence.Models.EntityMaps.Customers.MedicalQuestionnaires
{
    internal class GeneralQuestionnaireMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<GeneralQuestionnaire>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<GeneralQuestionnaire> entity)
        {
            entity.ToTable("GeneralQuestionnaires");
            entity.HasKey(gq => gq.Id);
            entity.Property(gq => gq.Id).HasColumnName("Id").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            entity.Property(gq => gq.IsPrivateHealthInsurance).HasColumnName("IsPrivateHealthInsurance").HasColumnType("bit").IsRequired();
            entity.Property(gq => gq.HealthInsuranceFoundation).HasColumnName("HealthInsuranceFoundation").HasColumnType("varchar").HasMaxLength(60).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(gq => gq.BloodType).HasColumnName("BloodType").HasColumnType("int").IsRequired();
            entity.Property(gq => gq.IsPregnant).HasColumnName("IsPregnant").HasColumnType("bit").IsRequired();
            entity.Property(gq => gq.PregnancyWeeks).HasColumnName("PregnancyWeeks").HasColumnType("int").IsRequired();
            entity.Property(gq => gq.IsRegularPhysicalActivity).HasColumnName("IsRegularPhysicalActivity").HasColumnType("bit").IsRequired();
            entity.Property(gq => gq.RegularPhysicalActivityPerWeek).HasColumnName("RegularPhysicalActivityPerWeek").HasColumnType("int").IsRequired();
            entity.Property(gq => gq.IsSurgeryInTheLastFiveYears).HasColumnName("IsSurgeryInTheLastFiveYears").HasColumnType("bit").IsRequired();
            entity.Property(gq => gq.SurgeryTypeAndWhen).HasColumnName("SurgeryTypeAndWhen").HasColumnType("varchar").HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(gq => gq.IsSmoker).HasColumnName("IsSmoker").HasColumnType("bit").IsRequired();
            entity.Property(gq => gq.SmokerForHowLong).HasColumnName("SmokerForHowLong").HasColumnType("int").IsRequired();
            entity.Property(gq => gq.IsAnyMedication).HasColumnName("IsAnyMedication").HasColumnType("bit").IsRequired();
            entity.Property(gq => gq.MedicationTypeAndWhen).HasColumnName("MedicationTypeAndWhen").HasColumnType("varchar").HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(gq => gq.AnythingElseToKnow).HasColumnName("AnythingElseToKnow").HasColumnType("varchar").HasMaxLength(256).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(gq => gq.MedicalQuestionnaireId).HasColumnName("MedicalQuestionnaireId").HasColumnType("int").IsRequired();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If `Add-Migrations` worked, then it would generate code to perform the migration. Are you seeing that code added to your solution?

Comment: Hi, yes I have the three classes automatically added to the solution the 'InitialCreate.cs, InitialCreate.Designer.cs and the MyContextModelSnapshot.cs'

Comment: Confirm that the model you edited has been implemented in your DbContext (MasterGymContext)

Comment: Hi, yes I confirmed that and not, the same. It continue without apply changes to the database. thank's to comment

Comment: Another things I tried in the class that contain the 'IEntityTypeConfiguration<GeneralQuestionnaire> is.. change the access modifier 'internal' for 'public'. The same way I tried too another way to implement the method 'modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(MasterGymContext).Assembly)' for 'modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new GeneralQuestionnaireMap())' and not too, that continue without work.. the same message 'No migrations were applied'.

Comment: Do you have multiple DBContext in this project or solution? If so, please ensure you are firing `Update-Database` on the correct one.

Comment: If you're running this from the NuGet Package Manager console, double check that the project that contains the migrations is selected AND that it's been built, AND that it's using the connection string for the correct database.

Comment: Hi Priyanka, yes I have more projects layer in the solution. And the project layer 'Persistence' exclusively for handle the transactions with the database.. I configure the layer 'Persistence' as the default project and I added the class 'MasterGymContextFactory' to be able to handle migrations without having the class 'Startup.cs'

Comment: Hi Merkle, yes the project layer is the same contain the 'DbContext' and the 'Migrations' folder. And is the project 'Persistence'. The connection string is correct, otherwise I could not add the migration and the database would not have been created. Thank's

Answer (score 0):

If you have your migrations stored in a different assembly (as it seems from the comments on the question), then you need to specify this assembly when you connect to the database;

```cs
options.UseSqlServer(
    connectionString,
    x => x.MigrationsAssembly("MyApp.Migrations"));
```

(from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/projects?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)

Comment: Hi, I using the 'Migrations' folder in the same assembly contain the DbContext.  I have the assembly as follows..

Comment: I have the assembly as follows.. 'MasterGym.Persistence' is the whole project, like any folder added, so, my assemblies are: 'MasterGym.Persistence.Migrations' and 'MasterGym.Persistence.Models'. 

NOTE: I add the application name to every project layer before for example: 'MasterGym.Data', 'MasterGym.Persistence', 'MasterGym.Business'.

Comment: I tried the option you show me, and I write: 'builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, x => x.MigrationsAssembly("MasterGym.Persistence.Migrations"));'

But I received: Could not load file or assembly 'MasterGym.Persistence, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Thank's for comment

Comment: use the assembly name not he namespace. builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, x => x.MigrationsAssembly("MasterGym.Persistence"));

Comment: Is your migration assembly a dependency of your project? If not, it won't be copied to the output folder.

Answer (score 0):

Common Problem: if you use `dotnet ef migrations add xxxx` the generated files are not attached to the project.
So when you run the database update, there are no new migration files in the project.

The solution is to go to your Visual Studio IDE and "Add->Existing" and attach the generated file. Then run update and that would work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move migration run to the Database context constructor:

```
public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options) 
{ 
   Database.Migrate(); 
}
```

If you got error: "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational'" add it to the startup project.
[EF Core NuGet Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/nuget-packages)